# Extract all rows from excel that match with with a column

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an excel with some columns in sheet A. In another sheet B I have a column with some values. This column in sheet B is in relation with another column in sheet A. I am trying to extract all the rows in sheet A that matches with the values in the column of sheet B. How to do this in excel? But without using macros, only formulas.

Comment: What have you tried? It sounds like a `VLOOKUP` might help you to determine which rows match, at least.

Comment: I have not tried anything because I have no idea on how to do this. Thanks for your suggestion I will try it.